# Python: How to convert response of content to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try but can't find any related topic with my issues.
I request a url and manage to get the content. However, I unable to convert it to pandas dataframe

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('http://www.gtf.com/Jad/JsonstData?qryId=Rll',headers=headers)
content = page.content[len('{}&& '):] if page.content.startswith('{}&& ') else page.content
>>>pd.read_csv(content)
```

It return the below errors

`{ID:1048,N:'ZICO H
ldgs',SIP:'',NC:'40W',R:'',I:'',M:'t',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:21.000,B:'0.171',S:'0.250',SV:121.000,O:0,H:0,L:0,
V:0.000,SC:'A',PV:0.255,P:0,BL:'100',P_:'',V_:''},{ID:1049,N:'ZNH ADR US$',SIP:'',NC:'K3TD',R:'',I:'',M:'g',L
T:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:0,B:'',S:'',SV:0,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'7',PV:18.070,P:0,BL:'10',P_:'',V_:''}]} does not
 exist`

How to get the desired output as

```
ID N        SIP  NC ..........BL P_ X V
0  2ndChance Nan CDWW         100 Nan Nan Nan
1  3Cnergy   Nan 502..........200 Nan Nan Nan
```

It needs to be in Pandas Dataframe form. How to convert from content to Pandas Dataframe?

Comment: why are you using read_csv? the return page.content is not in csv format.

Comment: You have a Json object not a CSV

Comment: @alec_djinn It is not even in proper json format.

Comment: this json looks broke to me

Comment: @hcheung  how to clean it up to become a proper json? I thought it is the correct json format

Comment: json object is data object with double quote, like {"name":"letterman"}. Where did you get the API from? maybe read the API documentation or find out the data schema

Answer (score 0):

The data is not in csv format, nor json format. It is data object that might be designed to be used by Javascript. For example, with the strange `'{} && '`(an empty object AND another object) prefix taken away, I can easily retrieve data element using javascript:

```
data = {
identifier:'ID',
label:'As at 08-03-2018 5:06 PM',
items:[{
  ID:0,
  N:'2ndChance W200123',
  SIP:'',
  NC:'CDWW',
  R:'',
  I:'',
  M:'',
  LT:0.009,
  C:0.000,
  VL:108.200,
  BV:2149.900,
  B:'0.008',
  S:'0.009',
  SV:7218.300,
  O:0.009,
  H:0.009,
  L:0.008,
  V:873.700,
  SC:'5',
  PV:0.009,
  P:0.000,
  BL:'100',
  P_:'X',
  V_:''
}]
}
console.log(data.items[0].N);
```

This would return

```
2ndChance W200123'
```

You should check the API documentation to see the proper usage of the return data. Alternatively, you could save the return data as a text file, and manually edit it, and use Javascript to read in the file like I did, and convert it into json or whatever format you need for further processing.

Answer (score -1):

`read_csv` function get a file name as an argument. If you want to form a DataFrame use simple 
`df = pd.DataFrame(content,index=list(range(0,len(content)))`

Comment: It did not give e output from my side. Is it working at your side?

Comment: The command looks like incomplete `>>> pd.DataFrame(content,index=list(range(0,len(content)))
... `. it is what it shown with .... after the command

Comment: sorry, the last bracket is missed: `pd.DataFrame(content,index=list(range(0,len(content))))`

Comment: it return `pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` now

Comment: you need to have a dictionary format, but it doesn't a dictionary: some extra square bracket in the end, for example, string variables without quotes